# How to filter model (User) using url param in views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In one of my templates I have this line

```
<input type="submit" name="username" value="{{ post.user }}" />
```

so after I click this button to submit, my url has /?username=hi.

Then in my views.py I have this

```
def finduser(request):
    username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
    if username is not None:
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    return render(request, 'user.html', {'user': user})
```

My question is what is the correct syntax of retrieving the "hi" from the url and then searching all User objects until I find the one with the username "hi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
username = request.GET['username']
```

This is if course [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for the `username` in the `request.GET` dictionary.

From the [`HttpRequest.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) documentation:

> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP GET parameters.

**Final Code:**

```
def finduser(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username') # lookup 'username' key
    user = None # also define this otherwise will raise error in the last line if username was 'None'
    if username is not None:
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    return render(request, 'user.html', {'user': user})
```